Maharshal on halachah vs secular law
This page says:

Rabbi Shlomo Luria, nearly 500 years ago, argued that with the
exception of great moral deficiencies like murder, stealing and
deception, the Torah mostly describes behavior between Jews and relies
on secular law for the rest.

Can anyone show me where the Maharshal says this? Many thanks.

If you don't get an answer here, you can try reaching out to the author directly: https://www.walkingstick.org/contact.html

The Maharshal in Yam Shel Shlomo on tree last perek in Bava Kama, Siman 20 says that gezel akum cannot be assur min hatorah, because the laws of the Torah are meant only to be between Jews not non Jews. He doesn’t mention moral laws as an exception though. Here is a screenshot of the piece

The Chacham Tzvi in Siman 26 quotes it and disagrees. The Shach Choshen Mishpat 359 quotes it as well.
